# Finding the Median of three numbers in Python. 3.8.2

Tags: python

How would I find the median of three numbers without using this function in python is there another way  median_1 = statistics.median(alpha_1)

```py
    enter code here
def median(alpha_1):
    #median_1 = sorted(alpha)
    median_1 = statistics.median(alpha_1)
    return median_1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # FIXME 1: Print the statement where you say what the program is going to do
    
    num_1 = int(input("Input first number:\n"))
    num_2 = int(input("Input second number:\n"))
    num_3 = int(input("Input third number:\n"))
    # FIXME 2: Propmt the user to input 3 numbers
    c = num_1, num_2, num_3
    f = median(c)
    print("The median is",f)
```

Comment: Try sorting the list and then choosing the middle value.

Comment: If you have a function that takes in *exactly* three numbers (`foo(a, b, c)`), then you can use logic in the form of several if-statements to determine which number is the middle. If you wanted something more scalable/practical, then why not use `statistics.median`?

Comment: @thegamecracks you are completely right it does the job but for some reason when I submit the program it says it isn't right but statistics.median is more practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most efficient for larger arrays, but for only three elements it will be fine:

```
def find_median_three_elements(my_list):
    return sorted(my_list)[1]
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your method but I'm using a function and my output has to return as a single number like 1 or 2.

Comment: That line does return a single number when alpha_1 is a list.  Just return that line within your function.  I edited my post to be more clear.

Comment: I understand that but I'm letting the user input numbers in I'm not using a list I have to input three numbers and I need a calculation that prints out the median.

Comment: This function does calculate the median.  If you need to take in user input and print output, that's a different question.

Comment: I updated my post with a clear example now. Can you see what I'm kind of saying?

Comment: What error are you getting?  It should work if you use the code I wrote.  You may have forgotten the `[1]`.

Comment: It works but I think it's something wrong with the place I submit my program because it's running in Pycharm and returning the right solution. Thanks for the help but I think it's beyond my control.